# SystemVerilog name alias

Tags: system-verilog

Does SystemVerilog enables aliases for module instances and enumerations? Eg, how could I code this:

```
enum logic {foo, bar} myEnum
enum logic {baz, qux} myEnum
```

ie, `baz` and `qux` are aliases of `foo` and `bar` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **let** construct can do this for any expression

```
enum logic {foo, bar} myEnum
let baz = foo;
let qux = bar;
```

You cannot alias an instance name.

Answer (score 0):

They cannot be aliased, but the can be casted/converted. Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 6.19.4 *Enumerated types in numerical expressions*. Example for the LRM:

> ```
> typedef enum {Red, Green, Blue} Colors;
> typedef enum {Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa,Su} Week;
> Colors C;
> Week W;
> int I;
> C = Colors'(C+1);            // C is converted to an integer, then added to
>                              // one, then converted back to a Colors type
> C = C + 1; C++; C+=2; C = I; // Illegal because they would all be
>                              // assignments of expressions without a cast
> C = Colors'(Su);             // Legal; puts an out of range value into C
> I = C + W;                   // Legal; C and W are automatically cast to int
> ```